# Display list of custom post type which match taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to add a snippet in my Wordpress sidebar which displays a list of links to posts which match a criteria.

I'm using a Custom Post Type **cars** and a taxonomy **car-types** and I'd like to display a list of links to **cars** which are part of the **car-types** taxonomy.

So in short. Display list of links where post is a custom post type called **cars** and the **car-types** taxonomy is **SUV**

Is there a way of doing this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help out.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

```
<?php
$args = array
(
    'post_type' => 'cars',
    'tax_query' => array
     (
        array
        (
            'taxonomy' => 'car-types',
            'field'    => 'slug', //or name or term_id
            'terms'    => 'suv',
        )
     )
);
$car_query = new WP_Query($args);?>
<?php if($car_query->have_posts()):?>
    <ul>
        <?php while($car_query->have_posts()): $car_query->the_post();?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```